# Tool for inserting JSON into JavaDoc?

Tags: java, json, api, documentation, javadoc

I am using [MireDot](http://www.miredot.com/) for generating documentation for my REST service.

While it is awesome for generating the models and general information on the resources, I don't believe it currently has a way of "nicely" adding concrete example input/output.

That said, I am resorting to pure JavaDoc for writing the Json examples. And it's painful.

Does anybody know of any tool out there that helps write JavaDoc... and in particular makes it easy to insert formatted JSON/etc into it?

Comment: In the meantime, I am copy/pasting the HTML from [here](http://jsonprettyprint.com/) (which works alright, I guess...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old question I posted when I was just experimenting with ways to document an API.

Eventually I switched to [Apiary](http://apiary.io/blueprint) over MireDot, which makes this task trivial.  The reason for this transition was mostly to decouple the JavaDoc from the actual API documentation, as I found coupling those two can create a very messy code-base for a sophisticated API that requires a lot of documentation.

Ideally would have built documentation using an all-encompassing API management platform like Mashery or the like, but at the time that was not an option.